# Почему новые работы в галерее генерируются только один раз?

Tags: jquery

Верстаю макет. Там есть типо галерея работ, вот код:

```js
$(function () {
    let gallery = $(".works__content").clone();
    $(".works__more__btn").click(function () {
        $(".works__content").append(gallery);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.works {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.works__headline {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Parangon 530 C";
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  padding-left: 186px;
  padding-right: 151px;
  background-image: url(../img/works/OUR_PROJECTS.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.works__text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #303263;
  padding-top: 21px;
}

.works__content__bigRow {
  display: flex;
}

.works__content__bigRow__item {
  width: 50%;
}

.works__content__smallRow {
  display: flex;
}

.works__content__smallRow__item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 327.61px;
}

.works__more {
  background-color: #303263;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 27px;
}

.works__more__btn {
  width: 240px;
  height: 66px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #6a6b8e;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Parangon 530 C";
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section class="works">
        <div class="works__text">
            <div class="works__headline">ПОСЛЕДНИЕ ПРОЕКТЫ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="works__content">
            <div class="works__content__bigRow">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/750x430/125" class="works__content__bigRow__item">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/750x430/200" class="works__content__bigRow__item">
            </div>
            <div class="works__content__smallRow">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/375x327/25" class="works__content__smallRow__item">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/375x327/50" class="works__content__smallRow__item">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/375x327/75" class="works__content__smallRow__item">
                <img src="https://www.placehold.it/375x327/100" class="works__content__smallRow__item">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="works__more">
            <button class="works__more__btn">ЕЩЕ БОЛЬШЕ</button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

У меня в jquery коду что-то не правильно и новые работы при нажатии на кнопку появляются только один раз.
Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот это сработает. просто замените в своём коде метод `clone()` на `html()`

```
$(function () {
    let gallery = $(".works__content").html();
    $(".works__more__btn").click(function () {
        $(".works__content").append(gallery);
    });
});
```

почему метод `clone()` не отрабатывал второй раз я не увереню. у меня есть предположение, но я не сильно образован в *jQuery* (и слава Богу). просто попрошу взять во внимание, что Вы брали `$(".works__content")`, клонировали и вставляли его **целиком вместе с родителем**, что каждый раз бы порождало всё глубже и глубже вложенность. Вам же нужно было клонировать лишь его содержимое